# Filter out exact words from part of string - java regex

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I want to match all lines that start with `fn-` except ones that use specific words after the hyphen.

match:

```
fn-bar
fn-foo
fn-foobarb
```

dont match (`foobar` and `fubar` are my exact negative filters):

```
fn-foobar
fn-fubar

xn-blah
```

So far I have:

```
(fn)-(?!(fubar|foobar)$)
```

which does not match the whole line

Comment: Your attempt was correct, just needed to add `.+` to get full match like: `^fn-(?!(fubar|foobar)$).+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the word delimiter `\b` to avoid matching the "*foobar*" and "*fubar*" words. Instead in order to avoid whole line issue, it's sufficient to antepose the negation of the full phrases you don't want to match.

```
(?!fn-foobar\b|fn-fubar\b)fn-.*
```

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/X7hlns/1).

Comment: Thank you! `fn-.*` was helpful. I think I'm going with `(?!fn-(foobar|fubar)$)fn-.*`